# Can't run the BlackBerry 10 jQuery Mobile theme kitchensink

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry-10

I downloaded the [BlackBerry 10 jQuery Mobile theme](https://github.com/blackberry/jQueryMobile-BB10-Theme) and I wanted to try how it works on the Dev Alpha.

I created this config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" 
version="1.0.0.0" rim:header="JQKS">
<author href="http://www.dandandin.net/"
rim:copyright="Copyright 2012 Dandandin.net">Dandandin.net</author>
<name>JQ Kitchensink</name>
<description>An app to test jquery</description>
<icon src="img/generic_81_81_placeholder.png" />
<content src="index.html"/>

<feature id="blackberry.invoke" version="1.0.0"/>
</widget>
```

and I placed it on /kitchensink

Then I packaged /kitchensink and loaded on my dev alpha, but I get this when I launch it:

[image: error]

I can press OK, but the application is frozen.

If I load it on my local webserver, and browse from the dev alpha it works, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work, you have to update to the latest 1.0.3.8 SDK.

I had 1.0.2 and it didn't work.